# parameter and response not working in swagger ui in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

This written comments not working for me It is not showing prameters and response in UI.

```js
// Routes
/**
* @swagger
* /test:
*      get:
*           description: Returns all users
*      parameters:
*               - name: customer
*                 in: query
*                 description: Model name
*                 required: true
*                 schema:
*                   type: string
*                   format: string
*      responses:
*          '200':
*               description: Successfully returned paginated records
*          '403':
*               description: Not enough permissions read_modelName
*/
```

Comment: The indentation appears to be wrong and also "pamrameters"?!

Comment: ok parameters was typo here.
but I am not getting proper indentation can you show some indentation format/example?
and should I use "response" inside get? or outside like above?

Answer (score 0):

You should indent each new line just two spaces. If you do not indent accordingly, the swagger UI will not render properly. See this documentation for an example: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/.

You may want to also install a yaml formatter to help with formatting Swagger, but if you choose to go without it, make sure to be aware of spacing because that is your current issue.